# Use Roslyn in NetStandard2.0 project to compile dynamically created code

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-standard

I'm trying to create a reusable .NET Standard 2.0 library that uses Roslyn to dynamically compile code at runtime to an in-memory assembly. This dynamically created assembly contains classes that derive from a base class that is part of the library. I instantiate them via reflection in the apps that reference the library. The project structure looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

Suppose that I have the following type in my netstandard2.0 library:

```cs
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public abstract int CalculateSomething();
    }
}
```

I then create the following unit test in a .NET Core 2.2 project:

```cs
namespace NetCore2_2.Tests
{
    public static class RoslynTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public static void CompileDynamicallyAndInvoke()
        {
            // Create syntax tree with simple class
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
using System;
using MyLibrary;

namespace Foo
{
    public sealed class Bar : BaseClass
    {
        public override int CalculateSomething()
        {
            return (int) Math.Sqrt(42);
        }
    }
}");
            // Create compilation, include syntax tree and reference to core lib
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                "MyDynamicAssembly.dll",
                new[] { syntaxTree },
                new[]
                {
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(BaseClass).Assembly.Location)
                },
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(
                    OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                    optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release)
            );

            // Compile it to a memory stream
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var result = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);

            // If it was not successful, throw an exception to fail the test
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var diagnostic in result.Diagnostics)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(diagnostic.ToString());
                }

                throw new XunitException(stringBuilder.ToString());
            }

            // Otherwise load the assembly, instantiate the type via reflection and call CalculateSomething
            var dynamicallyCompiledAssembly = Assembly.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());
            var type = dynamicallyCompiledAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar");
            var instance = (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            int number = instance.CalculateSomething();
            Assert.Equal((int) Math.Sqrt(42), number);
        }
    }
}
```

In this test, I first parse a piece of C# code that derives from `BaseClass` in the netstandard2.0 library. This piece of code additionally references `System.Math`. I then create a C# compilation object that includes references to the core lib (of .NET Core 2.2) and my library. This compilation object emits the DLL to a memory stream. If compiling fails, the test will fail with an exception that contains all diagnostics.

This unit test does fail with the following error message:

(7,31): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

(11,26): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

**I have the following questions:**

- **Is this not working because the Roslyn NuGet package is referenced in a .NET Standard 2.0 project and thus always tries to compile to the netstandard2.0 Target Framework Moniker?** I suspect that netstandard2.0 has a different definition of `System.Object` that forwards to the actual implementation of the target platform. And this forwarding definition is not referenced in my compilation unit.
- **Is there a way to change the target framework?** I looked at `CSharpCompilationOptions` and `EmitOptions`, but couldn't find anything that let's me change the target framework.
- **Do I maybe need to use another Roslyn NuGet package such as [Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset)?** I try to avoid this because actually want to use the default compilers instead of the ones in the NuGet package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's not working because your library, which contains `BaseClass`, targets `.netstandard2.0` (it means that this library references `netstandard.dll 2.0`) and this assumes that your library, which references library with `BaseClass`, should have a reference to `netstandard.dll 2.0` to correctrly resolve all corresponding types. So you should add reference on them (the `netstandard.dll` for `.net47` or the similar `.netstandard.dll` for `.netcore2.2`). 
  (By the way, when you reference `.netstandard2.0` from `.net47` library you probably should add a couple of additional libraries as reference from `path_to_visual_studio\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions`)
- Roslyn `Compilation` doesn't know anything about **target framework** and it should not know anything about it. `Compilation` works with trees and references (and with some options and metadata of references  of course), so you should manually append references that will be required in compilation. (By the way, if you have a `csproj` or a `sln` file you may use `MsBuildWorkspace` that allow to get a ready compilation from the project or solution file, in the most of cases)
- I suggest to create `Compilation` by hand if you know or can find out all references that will be required in compilation, else try to use [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild) to analyze `.csproj` or `.sln` files and then retrieve `Compilation` from them. `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset` just gives to you possibility to compile your project by compilers not are installed on your system, but are contained in this package.

Comment: George, thank you so much for your comprehensive answer. One more question: would you think it's better to move away from using netstandard2.0 for the library and instead use multi-targeting for net, nercoreapp, etc? Is this a proper way to get around manually resolving the correct netstandard DLLs? Because at runtime, it won't be that easy to get hold of a csproj file where the actual framework is configured. Maybe there's a way to use reflection to obtain these infos?

Comment: @feO2x, If you will use multitargeting it assumes that you will have a several different compilations for your library, compilation for `.net`, `.netcore` and so on. They will different because they have a different references by targeting a platform. So if you have the easy way to get this compilation for your library, it would be easy to use instead of manually resolving the `.netstandard.dll`. I think that the easy way to avoid resolving is to use a one target platform for all projects, of course if you can do that.